# C# & SQL Server : how to set quote_identifier off in ole db connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I've inherited an Access DB and migrated the data to a SQL Server DB. I would like to know if there's a similar parameter to QuoteId (ODBC) for OLE DB (I'm forced to use OLE DB here) for the connection string. This would allow me to set it only once in the config and have it done with.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please let me know if you need further information, but I think the key issue is just to know if there's an equivalent to OCDB-QuoteId for the OLE DB connection string (MS doesn't state any in their help pages).

Thanks a bunch